# Successor of VTI's SCP1000 Family of Absolute Pressure Sensors

Tags: sensor, components, component-selection, pressure

VTI's SCP1000 product family is a range of ceramic capacitive pressure sensors that have reached the end of their lifespan. It has been suggested that certain sensors designed by others (like Bosch Sensortec and STMicroelectronics) could be a "suitable substitute, but not a direct replacement."

However, following Murata's acquisition of VTI, has there been an offering from Murata that supersedes the SCP1000 series, in a manner recommended for use by designers who have used SCP1000?

Otherwise, how does the performance of the BMP280 from Bosch Sensortec and the LPS25HBTR from STMicroelectronics compare with that of the SCP1000 for electro-meteorological applications?